# Upgrading brew in El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, macos

I just upgraded to `El Capitan`, and when I tried updating `brew` I got the following error:

```
$ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Before I proceed with the `chown` recommendation, given that El Capitan just came out, is that the right way to proceed here? Why is this step necessary, and **what are any potential undesirable consequences** of running this command?

In case it helps, I found two issues about El Capitan in `brew`: [40837](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40837) and [41665](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41665) but a solution to this problem wasn't immediately clear. What can I do to continue to use `brew` in El Capitan reliably?

Comment: Well did you do as the message suggested, change ownership of `/usr/local`?

Comment: This raises an excellent question for the case of multiple users (or one user with multiple accounts having different profiles) on the same machine.

Comment: Typing `sudo chown -R` gives me the willies. It doesn’t matter what the other parameters are. I have more than Homebrew in `/usr/local`, and it’s not an obviously-safe command. I confirmed via Time Machine that installing El Capitan `chown`ed, exclusively, `/usr/local`, and not subdirectories. I was thus able to get away with doing a non-recursive reversion, i.e. `sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local`. YMMV.

Comment: @duozmo is right. The `-R` in `sudo chown -R` is really heavy handed. That's tantamount to Brew claiming domain over the entirety of `/usr/local`

Answer (score 31):

I mean they give you the solution right there. I had the same problem and I just ran:

```
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

and it worked.

Comment: +1 I also needed to reset my user's permissions as described. No further issues after this little tweak - homebrew and my packages have been very reliable on 10.11.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: One might assume that Apple locked down /usr/local for a reason and that this fix is NOT appropriate for El Capitan. I'm googling now to see if Apple provides some guidance. The question is "... given that El Capitan just came out, is that the right way to proceed here?"

Comment: @MichaelWelch The answer was posted before that edit.

Comment: Sorry @DisplayName I should have looked at the timestamps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md - I ran `$ brew doctor` and discovered that a `flac` dependency was missing. After `$ brew install flac` I had to stubbornly run `$ brew update` a couple more times.

Comment: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Comment: With Mac OS High Sierra 10.13, this sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local does not work for me. After I re-install using: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" brew works for me. Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3285

Answer (score 9):

We no longer need to break our heads about this. I risked the advice and did the suggested permission change. Then, on updating to the latest homebrew I got this reassuring message:

> Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you can return /usr/local to its default ownership with:
>     sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local

Comment: So how to solve this issue?

Comment: @RajeshMaurya use the solution by karolus

Answer (score 8):

Per some of the security questions above, the dialog does give instructions to reset after a successful brew update. After running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

And then

```
brew update
```

After the update has successfully run, the dialog should indicate doing this:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local
```

After that has been run, that should alleviate any security concerns with MacOS 10.12

Comment: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 6):

The given solution did **not** work for me:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

This variation worked for me:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/`

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/ worked for me on the latest macOS

Comment: chown: /usr/local/: Operation not permitted

Comment: add `sudo` then type in root level password

Comment: Still chown: /usr/local/: Operation not permitted even if I type in the root password.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by use this command `sudo chown -R admin /usr/local`.

Answer (score -1):

please look at the SIP with :

```
csrutil status
```

the system integrity protection is fixed at "enable", with the last Apple attribute 'restricted":

```
csrutil
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem stated in the question?

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me.

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

Comment: Both of these solutions do not work for me. It still shows: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score -2):

the system integrity protection needs to be disabled.
You can do it with this.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0";osascript -e 'tell app "loginwindow" to «event aevtrrst»’
```

This disables System Integrity Protection system wide. I believe you can also do it from the Recovery Mode. You still have to type in your root password when doing things with sudo, but you aren't locked out by SIP. You also don't then go opening up directories inadvertently trying to set permissions.

Comment: There is no need to disable SIP in order to change ownership below `/usr/local`.